# Exiting a foreach within Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having just started with Angular I have struggled a little, now something as easy as a foreach loop seems pretty easy? If an element is found then return false and don't do anything below.

```
$scope.addFav = function($text, $link, $icon)
{

    var $favlist = $scope.favorites;

    $favlist.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        console.log(element.name);
        console.log($text);
        if (element.name == $text)
        {
            console.log("Found");
            return false;
        }

    });

    $favlist.unshift({href: $link, name: $text, icon:$icon});

    if($favlist.length > 5)
        $favlist.pop();

    $scope.favorites = $favlist;

    return false;
};
```

My use case

```
<i class="fa fa-star-o" ng-click="addFav(item.name, item.href, item.icon);"
```

My question is where am I going wrong? The console is logged "Found" fine, but it doesn't stop the rest.

Comment: Do you want to stop code below forEach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning inside `forEach` callback won't prevent code outside from executing. In this case it's better to use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to check if array contains necessary value, and after that use simple `if` block to return or continue.

```
$scope.addFav = function ($text, $link, $icon) {

    var $favlist = $scope.favorites,
        found = $favlist.some(function (element, index, array) {
            return element.name == $text;
        });

    if (found) {
        return false;
    } 

    $favlist.unshift({
        href: $link,
        name: $text,
        icon: $icon
    });

    if ($favlist.length > 5) $favlist.pop();

    $scope.favorites = $favlist;

    return false;
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought if figured that the return wouldn't work as I wanted but didn't know an alternative. How do you cope with the Angular Docs?

Comment: Well it's not really angular in this case, this is principal limitation of the language, you can't affect outer code from the loop (only it you throw exception :).